# Graph not showing

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have the following code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# # Two Pie Charts 

import time
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash import Input, Output, dcc, html

# Data treatment 

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/LEG2022_MediaMonitor/main/legislativas_2022_media_monitor_29jan2022/data_products/legislativas_2022_final_dataset_percentages.csv')

df_individuals  = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JorgeMiguelGomes/LEG2022_MediaMonitor/main/legislativas_2022_media_monitor_29jan2022/data_products/legislativas_2022_all_candidates_filtered.csv')

df_individuals = df_individuals.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0"])
df_indivuduals = df_individuals.drop(columns=["Post Created Date"])
df_individuals_melt=pd.melt(df_individuals,id_vars=['candidato','Page Name'])


# Styling 

pie_color_map = {
    "Angry":"#EB9486",
    "Love":"#CAE7B9"
}

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
                meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],
                )


app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        # First Row 
        dbc.Row(
            [
            dbc.Col(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "2vh", "width": "100%", "borderColor": "#CAE7B9","opacity": "unset"}),width={'size':2}),
            dbc.Col(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "2vh", "width": "100%", "borderColor": "#F3DE8A","opacity": "unset"}),width={'size':2}),
            dbc.Col(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "2vh", "width": "100%", "borderColor": "#EB9486","opacity": "unset"}),width={'size':2}),
            dbc.Col(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "2vh", "width": "100%", "borderColor": "#7E7F9A","opacity": "unset"}),width={'size':2}),
            dbc.Col(html.Hr(style={'borderWidth': "2vh", "width": "100%", "borderColor": "#97A7B3","opacity": "unset"}),width={'size':2}),
            ],className="g-0",
        ), # end of first row 


        dbc.Tabs(
            [
                dbc.Tab(label="About", tab_id="method", label_style={"color": "#CAE7B9"},tab_style={'background-color': '#97A7B3'},active_label_style={"background-color":"#080808"}),      
                dbc.Tab(label="Metrics by Totals", tab_id="totals", label_style={"color": "#F3DE8A"},tab_style={'background-color': '#7E7F9A'}, active_label_style={"background-color":"#080808"}),
                dbc.Tab(label="Stacked Analysis", tab_id="stacked", label_style={"color": "#EB9486"},tab_style={'background-color': '#F3DE8A'}, active_label_style={"background-color":"#080808"}),
                dbc.Tab(label="Love vs Angry", tab_id="love_angry", label_style={"color": "#7E7F9A"},tab_style={'background-color': '#EB9486'}, active_label_style={"background-color":"#080808"}),
                dbc.Tab(label="Conclusions", tab_id="conclusions", label_style={"color": "#97A7B3"},tab_style={'background-color': '#F3DE8A'}, active_label_style={"background-color":"#080808"}),
            ],
            id="tabs",
            active_tab="love_angry", # this is the tab that will be active when the user comes to the website 
        ), # end of tabs 
        html.Div(id="tab-content", className="p-5"),
    ]
)


# Callbacks 

# Pie Chart for Candidates 

# @app.callback(
#     Output(component_id='graph_individuals', component_property='figure'),
#     [Input(component_id='dropdown_candidates', component_property='value')],
# )

# def build_graph_individuals(column_chosen):
#     dff = df
#     totals_sentiment = dff.groupby(['candidato'])[['Love','Angry']].sum().reset_index()
#     totals_sentiment_melt = pd.melt(totals_sentiment,id_vars="candidato")
#     totals_sentiment_melt = totals_sentiment_melt[totals_sentiment_melt['candidato'] == column_chosen]
#     fig_individuals = px.pie(totals_sentiment_melt,names="variable",values="value",hole=0.5, color="variable",color_discrete_map=pie_color_map)
#     candidato_filter = column_chosen
#     return fig_individuals

# Pie Chart for Media Outlets     

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph_shares_comments', component_property='figure'),
    Output(component_id='graph_individuals', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown_media_outlet', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='dropdown_candidates', component_property='value')
)

def build_graphs(column_chosen, candidato_filter):
    
    # Data Treatment for candidate graph 
    dff = df
    totals_sentiment = dff.groupby(['candidato'])[['Love','Angry']].sum().reset_index()
    totals_sentiment_melt = pd.melt(totals_sentiment,id_vars="candidato")
    totals_sentiment_melt = totals_sentiment_melt[totals_sentiment_melt['candidato'] == column_chosen]

    # Data Treatment for media graph 
    dff_m = df[df['candidato']== candidato_filter]
    print(dff_m)
    totals_sentiment_media = dff_m.groupby(['Page Name'])[['Love','Angry']].sum().reset_index()
    totals_sentiment_media_melt = pd.melt(totals_sentiment_media,id_vars="Page Name")
    totals_sentiment_media_melt = totals_sentiment_media_melt[totals_sentiment_media_melt['Page Name'] == column_chosen]
    print("HELLO HELLO")
    print(totals_sentiment_media_melt)


    
    
    
    # Pice Charts

    

    fig_candidates = px.pie(totals_sentiment_melt,names="variable",values="value",hole=0.5, color="variable",color_discrete_map=pie_color_map)
    fig_media = px.pie(totals_sentiment_media_melt,names="variable",values="value",hole=0.6, color="variable",color_discrete_map=pie_color_map)
    
    return fig_candidates, fig_media 
    



# TABS CALLBACKS -------------------------------------

@app.callback(Output("tab-content", "children"),
    [Input("tabs", "active_tab")])

def switch_tab(at):
    if at == "love_angry":
        tab4_content = dbc.Row(
                        [
                            dbc.Col(
                                [ 
                                dcc.Dropdown(
                                id='dropdown_candidates',
                                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df_individuals_melt.candidato.unique()
                                    ],
                                    optionHeight=35,                        #height/space between dropdown options
                                    value='António Costa',             #dropdown value selected automatically when page loads
                                    disabled=False,                         #disable dropdown value selection
                                    multi=False,                            #allow multiple dropdown values to be selected
                                    searchable=True,                        #allow user-searching of dropdown values
                                    search_value='',                        #remembers the value searched in dropdown
                                    placeholder='Please select...',         #gray, default text shown when no option is selected
                                    clearable=True,                         #allow user to removes the selected value
                                    style={'width':"100%"},                 #use dictionary to define CSS styles of your dropdown
                                    # className='select_box',               #activate separate CSS document in assets folder
                                    # persistence=True,                     #remembers dropdown value. Used with persistence_type
                                    # persistence_type='memory'             #remembers dropdown value selected until...
                                    ),  
                                dbc.Col(
                                    dcc.Graph(id='graph_individuals'),
                                    ),
                                ],width={'size':6, 'offset':0}
                            ), 

                            dbc.Col(
                                [ 
                                dcc.Dropdown(
                                id='dropdown_media_outlet',
                                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in df['Page Name'].unique()
                                ],
                                optionHeight=35,                        #height/space between dropdown options
                                value='Agência Lusa',                   #dropdown value selected automatically when page loads
                                disabled=False,                         #disable dropdown value selection
                                multi=False,                            #allow multiple dropdown values to be selected
                                searchable=True,                        #allow user-searching of dropdown values
                                search_value='',                        #remembers the value searched in dropdown
                                placeholder='Please select...',         #gray, default text shown when no option is selected
                                clearable=True,                         #allow user to removes the selected value
                                style={'width':"100%"},                 #use dictionary to define CSS styles of your dropdown
                                # className='select_box',               #activate separate CSS document in assets folder
                                # persistence=True,                     #remembers dropdown value. Used with persistence_type
                                # persistence_type='memory'             #remembers dropdown value selected until...
                                                      
                                    ),  
                                dbc.Col(
                                    dcc.Graph(id='graph_shares_comments'),
                                    ),
                                ],width={'size':6, 'offset':0}
                            ), 

                        ],
        ),

        return tab4_content
    # Error Message 
    return html.P("FOR SUPPORT PURPOSES ONLY")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8888)
```

The code is running without errors **but** as you can see in the image below, the chart on the left side is not rendering, and I'm totally lost.
I have inserted a `print` command in the script, and when I change the dropdowns the values change accordingly as they should.

However the pie chart remains empty, like it's not getting any information.
Maybe I've been looking at the same code for more hours than I should, and I'm missing something really simple, but I just can't spot it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

[image: Dashboard_MediaMonitor]

*Disclosure* This is not a commercial project nor will I use it in any commercial way.

Comment: Do you mean the line chart is empty, your picture indicates that the pie chart is being rendered and is not empty?

Comment: I figured out the issue with your code, you needed to use candidato_filter as the filter for your total_sentiment_melt like this ```totals_sentiment_melt = totals_sentiment_melt[totals_sentiment_melt['candidato'] == candidato_filter]```

Comment: The tab is supposed to render two pie charts, where the one on the right is not rendering anything at all there should be a pie chart as well.

Comment: @DanielAlMouiee but that one is rendering as it should. Is the one with the media outlets that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were filtering with the wrong keyword for `totals_sentiment_melt`, use this to correct it:

```py
totals_sentiment_melt = totals_sentiment_melt[totals_sentiment_melt['candidato'] == candidato_filter]
```